# only one file is displayed on the list when multiple files are selected using jquery Multiple File Upload Plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am using jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin (which downloaded from [here](https://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/)). 
The uploading works fine. It saves the file to the server and the path at the database. But the only problem is when I am selecting multiple files. For example, if I select 2 files, only the 1st file that I select is displayed in the list of uploaded files. [(See example image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41DF0.png)

If I check if the files that I selected were saved in the database, the 2 files were already saved. So the only problem is why only the first file is displayed.

This is the js file that I have downloaded for this project and I don't know how to modify this one. Can someone help me through this?

Thank you so much.

```js
/*
 ### jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin v1.48 - 2012-07-19 ###
 * Home: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/
 * Code: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-multifile-plugin/
 *
 * Licensed under http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License
 ###
*/

/*# AVOID COLLISIONS #*/
;if(window.jQuery) (function($){
/*# AVOID COLLISIONS #*/
 
 // plugin initialization
 $.fn.MultiFile = function(options){
  if(this.length==0) return this; // quick fail
  
  // Handle API methods
  if(typeof arguments[0]=='string'){
   // Perform API methods on individual elements
   if(this.length>1){
    var args = arguments;
    return this.each(function(){
     $.fn.MultiFile.apply($(this), args);
    });
   };
   // Invoke API method handler
   $.fn.MultiFile[arguments[0]].apply(this, $.makeArray(arguments).slice(1) || []);
   // Quick exit...
   return this;
  };
  
  // Initialize options for this call
  var options = $.extend(
   {}/* new object */,
   $.fn.MultiFile.options/* default options */,
   options || {} /* just-in-time options */
  );
  
  // Empty Element Fix!!!
  // this code will automatically intercept native form submissions
  // and disable empty file elements
  $('form')
  .not('MultiFile-intercepted')
  .addClass('MultiFile-intercepted')
  .submit($.fn.MultiFile.disableEmpty);
  
  //### http://plugins.jquery.com/node/1363
  // utility method to integrate this plugin with others...
  if($.fn.MultiFile.options.autoIntercept){
   $.fn.MultiFile.intercept( $.fn.MultiFile.options.autoIntercept /* array of methods to intercept */ );
   $.fn.MultiFile.options.autoIntercept = null; /* only run this once */
  };
  
  // loop through each matched element
  this
   .not('.MultiFile-applied')
   .addClass('MultiFile-applied')
  .each(function(){
   //#####################################################################
   // MAIN PLUGIN FUNCTIONALITY - START
   //#####################################################################
   
       // BUG 1251 FIX: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/comments/add/1251
       // variable group_count would repeat itself on multiple calls to the plugin.
       // this would cause a conflict with multiple elements
       // changes scope of variable to global so id will be unique over n calls
       window.MultiFile = (window.MultiFile || 0) + 1;
       var group_count = window.MultiFile;
       
       // Copy parent attributes - Thanks to Jonas Wagner
       // we will use this one to create new input elements
       var MultiFile = {e:this, E:$(this), clone:$(this).clone()};
       
       //===
       
       //# USE CONFIGURATION
       if(typeof options=='number') options = {max:options};
       var o = $.extend({},
        $.fn.MultiFile.options,
        options || {},
        ($.metadata? MultiFile.E.metadata(): ($.meta?MultiFile.E.data():null)) || {}, /* metadata options */
        {} /* internals */
       );
       // limit number of files that can be selected?
       if(!(o.max>0) /*IsNull(MultiFile.max)*/){
        o.max = MultiFile.E.attr('maxlength');
       };
       if(!(o.max>0) /*IsNull(MultiFile.max)*/){
        o.max = (String(MultiFile.e.className.match(/\b(max|limit)\-([0-9]+)\b/gi) || ['']).match(/[0-9]+/gi) || [''])[0];
        if(!(o.max>0)) o.max = -1;
        else           o.max = String(o.max).match(/[0-9]+/gi)[0];
       }
       o.max = new Number(o.max);
       // limit extensions?
       o.accept = o.accept || MultiFile.E.attr('accept') || '';
       if(!o.accept){
        o.accept = (MultiFile.e.className.match(/\b(accept\-[\w\|]+)\b/gi)) || '';
        o.accept = new String(o.accept).replace(/^(accept|ext)\-/i,'');
       };
       
       //===
       
       // APPLY CONFIGURATION
       $.extend(MultiFile, o || {});
       MultiFile.STRING = $.extend({},$.fn.MultiFile.options.STRING,MultiFile.STRING);
       
       //===
       
       //#########################################
       // PRIVATE PROPERTIES/METHODS
       $.extend(MultiFile, {
        n: 0, // How many elements are currently selected?
        slaves: [], files: [],
        instanceKey: MultiFile.e.id || 'MultiFile'+String(group_count), // Instance Key?
        generateID: function(z){ return MultiFile.instanceKey + (z>0 ?'_F'+String(z):''); },
        trigger: function(event, element){
         var handler = MultiFile[event], value = $(element).attr('value');
         if(handler){
          var returnValue = handler(element, value, MultiFile);
          if( returnValue!=null ) return returnValue;
         }
         return true;
        }
       });
       
       //===
       
       // Setup dynamic regular expression for extension validation
       // - thanks to John-Paul Bader: http://smyck.de/2006/08/11/javascript-dynamic-regular-expresions/
       if(String(MultiFile.accept).length>1){
        MultiFile.accept = MultiFile.accept.replace(/\W+/g,'|').replace(/^\W|\W$/g,'');
        MultiFile.rxAccept = new RegExp('\\.('+(MultiFile.accept?MultiFile.accept:'')+')$','gi');
       };
       
       //===
       
       // Create wrapper to hold our file list
       MultiFile.wrapID = MultiFile.instanceKey+'_wrap'; // Wrapper ID?
       MultiFile.E.wrap('<div class="MultiFile-wrap" id="'+MultiFile.wrapID+'"></div>');
       MultiFile.wrapper = $('#'+MultiFile.wrapID+'');
       
       //===
       
       // MultiFile MUST have a name - default: file1[], file2[], file3[]
       MultiFile.e.name = MultiFile.e.name || 'file'+ group_count +'[]';
       
       //===
       
       if(!MultiFile.list){
        // Create a wrapper for the list
        // * OPERA BUG: NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR ('list' is a read-only property)
        // this change allows us to keep the files in the order they were selected
        MultiFile.wrapper.append( '<div class="MultiFile-list" id="'+MultiFile.wrapID+'_list"></div>' );
        MultiFile.list = $('#'+MultiFile.wrapID+'_list');
       };
       MultiFile.list = $(MultiFile.list);
       
       //===
       
       // Bind a new element
       MultiFile.addSlave = function( slave, slave_count ){
        //if(window.console) console.log('MultiFile.addSlave',slave_count);
        
        // Keep track of how many elements have been displayed
        MultiFile.n++;
        // Add reference to master element
        slave.MultiFile = MultiFile;
        
        // BUG FIX: http://plugins.jquery.com/node/1495
        // Clear identifying properties from clones
        if(slave_count>0) slave.id = slave.name = '';
        
        // Define element's ID and name (upload components need this!)
        //slave.id = slave.id || MultiFile.generateID(slave_count);
        if(slave_count>0) slave.id = MultiFile.generateID(slave_count);
        //FIX for: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-multifile-plugin/issues/detail?id=23
        
        // 2008-Apr-29: New customizable naming convention (see url below)
        // http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_frm/thread/765c73e41b34f924#
        slave.name = String(MultiFile.namePattern
         /*master name*/.replace(/\$name/gi,$(MultiFile.clone).attr('name'))
         /*master id  */.replace(/\$id/gi,  $(MultiFile.clone).attr('id'))
         /*group count*/.replace(/\$g/gi,   group_count)//(group_count>0?group_count:''))
         /*slave count*/.replace(/\$i/gi,   slave_count)//(slave_count>0?slave_count:''))
        );
        
        // If we've reached maximum number, disable input slave
        if( (MultiFile.max > 0) && ((MultiFile.n-1) > (MultiFile.max)) )//{ // MultiFile.n Starts at 1, so subtract 1 to find true count
         slave.disabled = true;
        //};
        
        // Remember most recent slave
        MultiFile.current = MultiFile.slaves[slave_count] = slave;
        
        // We'll use jQuery from now on
        slave = $(slave);
        
        // Clear value
        slave.val('').attr('value','')[0].value = '';
        
        // Stop plugin initializing on slaves
        slave.addClass('MultiFile-applied');
        
        // Triggered when a file is selected
        slave.change(function(){
          //if(window.console) console.log('MultiFile.slave.change',slave_count);
          
          // Lose focus to stop IE7 firing onchange again
          $(this).blur();
          
          //# Trigger Event! onFileSelect
          if(!MultiFile.trigger('onFileSelect', this, MultiFile)) return false;
          //# End Event!
          
          //# Retrive value of selected file from element
          var ERROR = '', v = String(this.value || ''/*.attr('value)*/);
          
          // check extension
          if(MultiFile.accept && v && !v.match(MultiFile.rxAccept))//{
            ERROR = MultiFile.STRING.denied.replace('$ext', String(v.match(/\.\w{1,4}$/gi)));
           //}
          //};
          
          // Disallow duplicates
          for(var f in MultiFile.slaves)//{
           if(MultiFile.slaves[f] && MultiFile.slaves[f]!=this)//{
            //console.log(MultiFile.slaves[f],MultiFile.slaves[f].value);
            if(MultiFile.slaves[f].value==v)//{
             ERROR = MultiFile.STRING.duplicate.replace('$file', v.match(/[^\/\\]+$/gi));
            //};
           //};
          //};
          
          // Create a new file input element
          var newEle = $(MultiFile.clone).clone();// Copy parent attributes - Thanks to Jonas Wagner
          //# Let's remember which input we've generated so
          // we can disable the empty ones before submission
          // See: http://plugins.jquery.com/node/1495
          newEle.addClass('MultiFile');
          
          // Handle error
          if(ERROR!=''){
            // Handle error
            MultiFile.error(ERROR);
            
            // 2007-06-24: BUG FIX - Thanks to Adrian Wróbel <adrian [dot] wrobel [at] gmail.com>
            // Ditch the trouble maker and add a fresh new element
            MultiFile.n--;
            MultiFile.addSlave(newEle[0], slave_count);
            slave.parent().prepend(newEle);
            slave.remove();
            return false;
          };
          
          // Hide this element (NB: display:none is evil!)
          $(this).css({ position:'absolute', top: '-3000px' });
          
          // Add new element to the form
          slave.after(newEle);
          
          // Update list
          MultiFile.addToList( this, slave_count );
          
          // Bind functionality
          MultiFile.addSlave( newEle[0], slave_count+1 );
          
          //# Trigger Event! afterFileSelect
          if(!MultiFile.trigger('afterFileSelect', this, MultiFile)) return false;
          //# End Event!
          
        }); // slave.change()
        
        // Save control to element
        $(slave).data('MultiFile', MultiFile);
        
       };// MultiFile.addSlave
       // Bind a new element
       
       
       
       // Add a new file to the list
       MultiFile.addToList = function( slave, slave_count ){
        //if(window.console) console.log('MultiFile.addToList',slave_count);
        
        //# Trigger Event! onFileAppend
        if(!MultiFile.trigger('onFileAppend', slave, MultiFile)) return false;
        //# End Event!
        
        // Create label elements
        var
         r = $('<div class="MultiFile-label"></div>'),
         v = String(slave.value || ''/*.attr('value)*/),
         a = $('<span class="MultiFile-title" title="'+MultiFile.STRING.selected.replace('$file', v)+'">'+MultiFile.STRING.file.replace('$file', v.match(/[^\/\\]+$/gi)[0])+'</span>'),
         b = $('<a class="MultiFile-remove" href="#'+MultiFile.wrapID+'">'+MultiFile.STRING.remove+'</a>');
        
        // Insert label
        MultiFile.list.append(
         r.append(a,  ' ' , b)); b.click(function(){
         
          //# Trigger Event! onFileRemove
          if(!MultiFile.trigger('onFileRemove', slave, MultiFile)) return false;
          //# End Event!
          
          MultiFile.n--;
          MultiFile.current.disabled = false;
          
          // Remove element, remove label, point to current
          MultiFile.slaves[slave_count] = null;
          $(slave).remove();
          $(this).parent().remove();
          
          // Show most current element again (move into view) and clear selection
          $(MultiFile.current).css({ position:'', top: '' });
          $(MultiFile.current).reset().val('').attr('value', '')[0].value = '';
          
          //# Trigger Event! afterFileRemove
          if(!MultiFile.trigger('afterFileRemove', slave, MultiFile)) return false;
          //# End Event!
          
          return false;
        });
        
        //# Trigger Event! afterFileAppend
        if(!MultiFile.trigger('afterFileAppend', slave, MultiFile)) return false;
        //# End Event!
        
       }; // MultiFile.addToList
       // Add element to selected files list
       
       
       // Bind functionality to the first element
       if(!MultiFile.MultiFile) MultiFile.addSlave(MultiFile.e, 0);
       
       // Increment control count
       //MultiFile.I++; // using window.MultiFile
       MultiFile.n++;
       
       // Save control to element
       MultiFile.E.data('MultiFile', MultiFile);
       

   //#####################################################################
   // MAIN PLUGIN FUNCTIONALITY - END
   //#####################################################################
  }); // each element
 };
 
 /*--------------------------------------------------------*/
 
 /*
  ### Core functionality and API ###
 */
 $.extend($.fn.MultiFile, {
  /**
   * This method removes all selected files
   *
   * Returns a jQuery collection of all affected elements.
   *
   * @name reset
   * @type jQuery
   * @cat Plugins/MultiFile
   * @author Diego A. (http://www.fyneworks.com/)
   *
   * @example $.fn.MultiFile.reset();
   */
  reset: function(){
   var settings = $(this).data('MultiFile');
   //if(settings) settings.wrapper.find('a.MultiFile-remove').click();
   if(settings) settings.list.find('a.MultiFile-remove').click();
   return $(this);
  },
  
  
  /**
   * This utility makes it easy to disable all 'empty' file elements in the document before submitting a form.
   * It marks the affected elements so they can be easily re-enabled after the form submission or validation.
   *
   * Returns a jQuery collection of all affected elements.
   *
   * @name disableEmpty
   * @type jQuery
   * @cat Plugins/MultiFile
   * @author Diego A. (http://www.fyneworks.com/)
   *
   * @example $.fn.MultiFile.disableEmpty();
   * @param String class (optional) A string specifying a class to be applied to all affected elements - Default: 'mfD'.
   */
  disableEmpty: function(klass){ klass = (typeof(klass)=='string'?klass:'')||'mfD';
   var o = [];
   $('input:file.MultiFile').each(function(){ if($(this).val()=='') o[o.length] = this; });
   return $(o).each(function(){ this.disabled = true }).addClass(klass);
  },
  
  
  /**
   * This method re-enables 'empty' file elements that were disabled (and marked) with the $.fn.MultiFile.disableEmpty method.
   *
   * Returns a jQuery collection of all affected elements.
   *
   * @name reEnableEmpty
   * @type jQuery
   * @cat Plugins/MultiFile
   * @author Diego A. (http://www.fyneworks.com/)
   *
   * @example $.fn.MultiFile.reEnableEmpty();
   * @param String klass (optional) A string specifying the class that was used to mark affected elements - Default: 'mfD'.
   */
  reEnableEmpty: function(klass){ klass = (typeof(klass)=='string'?klass:'')||'mfD';
   return $('input:file.'+klass).removeClass(klass).each(function(){ this.disabled = false });
  },
  
  
  /**
   * This method will intercept other jQuery plugins and disable empty file input elements prior to form submission
   *
 
   * @name intercept
   * @cat Plugins/MultiFile
   * @author Diego A. (http://www.fyneworks.com/)
   *
   * @example $.fn.MultiFile.intercept();
   * @param Array methods (optional) Array of method names to be intercepted
   */
  intercepted: {},
  intercept: function(methods, context, args){
   var method, value; args = args || [];
   if(args.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array")<0) args = [ args ];
   if(typeof(methods)=='function'){
    $.fn.MultiFile.disableEmpty();
    value = methods.apply(context || window, args);
    //SEE-http://code.google.com/p/jquery-multifile-plugin/issues/detail?id=27
    setTimeout(function(){ $.fn.MultiFile.reEnableEmpty() },1000);
    return value;
   };
   if(methods.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array")<0) methods = [methods];
   for(var i=0;i<methods.length;i++){
    method = methods[i]+''; // make sure that we have a STRING
    if(method) (function(method){ // make sure that method is ISOLATED for the interception
     $.fn.MultiFile.intercepted[method] = $.fn[method] || function(){};
     $.fn[method] = function(){
      $.fn.MultiFile.disableEmpty();
      value = $.fn.MultiFile.intercepted[method].apply(this, arguments);
      //SEE http://code.google.com/p/jquery-multifile-plugin/issues/detail?id=27
      setTimeout(function(){ $.fn.MultiFile.reEnableEmpty() },1000);
      return value;
     }; // interception
    })(method); // MAKE SURE THAT method IS ISOLATED for the interception
   };// for each method
  } // $.fn.MultiFile.intercept
  
 });
 
 /*--------------------------------------------------------*/
 
 /*
  ### Default Settings ###
  eg.: You can override default control like this:
  $.fn.MultiFile.options.accept = 'gif|jpg';
 */
 $.fn.MultiFile.options = { //$.extend($.fn.MultiFile, { options: {
  accept: '', // accepted file extensions
  max: -1,    // maximum number of selectable files
  
  // name to use for newly created elements
  namePattern: '$name', // same name by default (which creates an array)
         /*master name*/ // use $name
         /*master id  */ // use $id
         /*group count*/ // use $g
         /*slave count*/ // use $i
         /*other      */ // use any combination of he above, eg.: $name_file$i
  
  // STRING: collection lets you show messages in different languages
  STRING: {
   remove:'X',
   denied:'You cannot select a $ext file.\nTry again...',
   file:'$file',
   selected:'File selected: $file',
   duplicate:'This file has already been selected:\n$file'
  },
  
  // name of methods that should be automcatically intercepted so the plugin can disable
  // extra file elements that are empty before execution and automatically re-enable them afterwards
  autoIntercept: [ 'submit', 'ajaxSubmit', 'ajaxForm', 'validate', 'valid' /* array of methods to intercept */ ],
  
  // error handling function
  error: function(s){
   /*
   ERROR! blockUI is not currently working in IE
   if($.blockUI){
    $.blockUI({
     message: s.replace(/\n/gi,'<br/>'),
     css: { 
      border:'none', padding:'15px', size:'12.0pt',
      backgroundColor:'#900', color:'#fff',
      opacity:'.8','-webkit-border-radius': '10px','-moz-border-radius': '10px'
     }
    });
    window.setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);
   }
   else//{// save a byte!
   */
    alert(s);
   //}// save a byte!
  }
 }; //} });
 
 /*--------------------------------------------------------*/
 
 /*
  ### Additional Methods ###
  Required functionality outside the plugin's scope
 */
 
 // Native input reset method - because this alone doesn't always work: $(element).val('').attr('value', '')[0].value = '';
 $.fn.reset = function(){ return this.each(function(){ try{ this.reset(); }catch(e){} }); };
 
 /*--------------------------------------------------------*/
 
 /*
  ### Default implementation ###
  The plugin will attach itself to file inputs
  with the class 'multi' when the page loads
 */
 $(function(){
  //$("input:file.multi").MultiFile();
  $("input[type=file].multi").MultiFile();
 });
 
 
 
/*# AVOID COLLISIONS #*/
})(jQuery);
/*# AVOID COLLISIONS #*/
```

Comment: Have you found any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found a solution to this. Just took a long time posting for an update.

Appending all the files uploaded is what I did here.

I count all the files being uploaded then I append all these files for viewing.

```
<!--APPEND UPLOADED NARRATIVE REPORT FILE (CREATE PAGE)-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    //*--For collapsible table to display uploaded files--*//
    var narrativefileCount = document.getElementById('narrativefileTable').getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
    if (narrativefileCount > 0) {
        $("#narrativefiles").html(narrativefileCount + " file(s) uploaded")
    }

    function Slide4() {
        $("#nr").slideToggle('fast');
    }

    $("#narrativefiles").click(function () {
        Slide4();
    });
});
</script>
```

Hoping it would also help someone. Thanks.